# Give IIS web application permission to access files on network drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

I have developed an Intranet web application using C# and .NET that authenticates users using Windows Authentication

One of the pages reads data from an excel file stored on a network drive and displays the information on screen. To access the area of the network drive where the excel file is stored you need to be a member of a certain active directory group.

When I run the application locally this works fine, as it will be running under my login ID which has permission to the network drive.

However when I go to the live version of the application on our web server I get

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   '\\foo\bar.xlsx' is denied.

I guess this is because the user that IIS is using doesn't have permission to the network drive.

I have set up the application pool in IIS to use `ApplicationPoolIdentity` which i assume uses `IIS_USRS` but how do i give that permission to the network drive?

If I change the application pool in IIS to use an account that has permissions, such as my details, instead of ApplicationPoolIdentity i get the following error instead:

> **Service Unavailable**
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should check where it has permission with Temp and add whatever user your app pool is running at to have permissions for it. try making it Everyone just for the checkpoint

Comment: You need the client download .xlsx file like a text file?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi no, the page reads in all the sheet names and populates a drop down with the sheet names as selectable options

Comment: @MerHardik my application pool is running with the built in account ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: Have you seen this some where? I mean do you sure it is possible?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi The web page runs fine under local host, the drop down list is populated correctly. I just want to know what I need to do to make it work on our intranet page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by adding the server account to the active directory group that has permission to view the folders.

Answer (score 0):

The .xlsx files has

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

mime type. Go to IIS that has problem, Click on **mime types** button and at the table check if it has the mime type i said.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it does have that in the list.

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS DENIED: 
Same error but different scenario. Using C# .NET to access Active Directory to change passwords via System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. I was able to read but get the access denied trying to right back, naturally. This was because the application did not have rights to modify Active Directory. To fix this, I had to add an account in web.config that had Account Operator AD rights.  Below is what I needed to add to get it to work for our situation.

```
<add key="adAdminUser" value="USERNAME"/>
<add key="adAdminPassword" value="PASSWORD"/>
<add key="adDomainFull" value="BLANK4US"/>
```